# Image disappear when url route

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

I am writing a web page to show image (image is dynamically generate by .Net charting) in a web.  I have used the asp.net web forms URL routing to navigate to this page. Once I use the URL routing the image appear on the page. Anyway this is working fine for normal page browse.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here to get a viable answer.  Can you please explain your problem a little more in detail?

Comment: when the issue is expand its like this.

Comment: i made more mean full question please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972745/issue-with-asp-net-web-form-url-routing-image-not-appera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your link to the image is using a relative path, and once you introduce routing you are working with a URL structure that appears to be deeper nested in the folder structure than it is.

When linking to the image for display I would recommend using root relative path something like `/Images/MyFile.jpg` rather than `../Images/MyFile.jpg`, or similar.

This way if your route changes, and additional "folders" appear in the route, the link will still work.

Comment: question with more detail are in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972745/issue-with-asp-net-web-form-url-routing-image-not-appera